# Field defines a relation with model 'MODEL', which is either not installed, or is abstract

Tags: django, django-models

Using custom user model in Django is like living in hell for me. After spending endless hours trying to get it done, now I face new problem: once I add some other app that depends on my custom user model I see this:
for example once I add `'django.contrib.admin'`, I see the error

```
admin.LogEntry.user: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'main.Usr', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
admin.LogEntry.user: (fields.E307) The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'main.usr', but app 'main' doesn't provide model 'usr'.
```

my settings is like

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'main.Usr'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'main', # my app
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'django.contrib.postgres',
]
```

Comment: Not sure if this will make a difference, but try moving your app to the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to suppress these system checks in order for django to load.
I put this in my `settings.py`

```
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = ['fields.E300', 'fields.E307']
```

I don't recommend to enable this line unless you really know that the tables of the designated models really exist in the database.

Comment: Thanks! This setting allowed us to see the real error (`Migration x.000X dependencies reference nonexistent parent node`)!